# Create a BitmapImage from a Byte array and display it on an Image object UWP Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm using this code to write a Byte Array inside a file BMP:

```
private async void ScriviBMP()
    {
        using (Stream stream = immagineBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(arrayImmagine, 0, arrayImmagine.Length);
        }
        StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        if (folder != null)
        {
            StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("area2_128x128" + ".bmp", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var storageStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, storageStream);
                var pixelStream = immagineBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
                var pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
                await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)immagineBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)immagineBitmap.PixelHeight, 48, 48, pixels);
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then i'm using this code to display the BMP image in a Image object

```
private async void VisBMP()
    {
        var file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("area2_128x128.bmp");
        using (var fileStream = (await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)))
        {
            var bitImg = new BitmapImage();
            //bitImg.UriSource = new Uri(file.Path);
            bitImg.SetSource(fileStream);
            image.Source = bitImg;
        }
    }
```

these functions take about 400 milliseconds to complete the process, that's a lot of time.
Is there a way to avoid the usage of a BMP file and use only a stream to display the image on the image object?
It can be that debugging the program can slow the processes? I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Is `immagineBitmap` a WriteableBitmap? Then you could directly assign it to the Source property of the Image control, like `image.Source = immagineBitmap;`

Comment: This question (and the answer by @michael-xu-msft) is relevant for all UWP apps, not just Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transfer the data buffer(arrayImmagine) to image in **InMemoryRandomAccessStream**.These codes take about 200ms.I tested with following pieces of code. In addition, you can reference this [article](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-image-in-a-windows-store-app/) to get more information.

```
        BitmapImage biSource = new BitmapImage();
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
            stream.Seek(0);
            await biSource.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        }

        image.Source = biSource;
```

Comment: While this is true, it still seems entirely redundant. OP could most certainly directly assign their WriteableBitmap to the Image's Source.

Comment: I have tried that directly assignning WriteableBitmap to the Image's Source,but it can not display the image correctly.