# How to convert jpeg data to image in UWP

Tags: image, uwp, jpeg

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(rr.Nodes[1].ToString(), LoadOptions.None);
xdoc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF - 8", "yes");


var q = from b in xdoc.Descendants("PictureNo")

        select b.Value;

foreach (string item in q.ToList())
    textBox2.Text = item;

if (textBox2.Text == String.Empty)
{

    Byte[] data2 = new Byte[0];
    data2 = (Byte[])(Convert.FromBase64String(textBox2.Text));
    string base64String1 = Convert.ToBase64String(data2, 0, data2.Length);
    image.Source = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String1;
```

Comment: Hi, ASP.NET same issue can work as below codes:

Comment: DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
            data = (Byte[])(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PictureNo"]);
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(data, 0, data.Length);
            Image2.ImageUrl="data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;
            Image1.ImageUrl="data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;
         }

Comment: If you have specific problems, cosider studying [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) , provide code respecting [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and your exception / expectation that do not get met by your code and I am sure SO will help you out.

Comment: If you want to add valuable information to your questions, `edit` the question, do not use comments for that.

Comment: Hi, how can I convert JPEG Data to image in UWP?

Comment: You should edit the question using the **edit** link above to add some info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to turn `Base64` string to `BitmapImage`, which you can then set as `Image.Source`.

```cs
public async Task<BitmapImage> Base64ToBitmapAsync(string source)
{
    var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(source);            
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
        await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

You first create a byte array from the `Base64` source and then use it as a `MemoryStream`, which you load as the source of the `BitmapImage`.

You then simply do:

```cs
image.Source = await Base64ToBitmapAsync( Convert.FromBase64String(textBox2.Text) );
```

Comment: Thank you vry much. image.Source = await Base64ToBitmapAsync( Textbox2.Text);    is enough and it's working

Comment: Hi, glad to help! If that solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer so that the question is resolved :-)  You can do it by clicking the grey tick mark under then arrows to the left of the answer.

Comment: regardless of the Base64-to-ByteArray transformation, I found this answer more helpful (from a different but similar question) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679185/997940

Comment: I think in this case the base64 was a crucial part of the question, the linked one does not deal with base64...